# String stream object in .NET library

Tags: .net

Is anyone aware of a .NET class for encapsulating a collection of objects (strings in my case) which allow for Stream-like reading, seeking, etc.  Essentially I need a List that has a GetNext method that will return the next object and update the current reading position.

This wouldn't be hard to impliment (possibly with extension methods) but I wanted to leverage any currently developed .NET classes that may already exist.

EDIT: I want to add that the data will always be accessed in a forward manner (i.e. no need to seek to a spedific position) or just reset to zero.  So it seems like an IEnumerator may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what IEnumerable/IEnumerator does. Just call GetEnumerator() on your list and use the IEnumerator's `Current`/`MoveNext()` members.

If you want more functionality in terms of moving the current record pointer, you might find what you need just using the `Take()` extension method. Implementing an IEnumerable which maintains internal state is also farily easy.

Comment: That worked.  Good idea.  I didn't even consider just using the Enumerator to perform this task.

Answer (score 2):

There's always IEnumerable.  Of course, the limitation is that you can't seek backwards.

Answer (score -1):

**[BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader_methods.aspx)**/**[BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter_methods.aspx)** has functions for serializing all of the primitive types.  As long as you know what type to expect, this should work for you.  Seeking will be hard if you expect it to maintain string boundaries, but will work great for forward-only reading of all primitives.

Comment: The poster just wants the objects, not the data.